# How could children from the past, who have magical abilities be introduced into society?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, magic, adaptability

The initial time they come from would be after 1900. And the different children would come from different years.

These children would have control of their powers and could keep them hidden if needed.

The public doesn't know about these children.

They are being maintained by a few rich members of society.

Their current situation is nice but it doesn't provide the children with a family.

Would these children fare well in a special foster home? Perhaps one that knows about their powers?

The children are currently concentrated in an institution together that helps them be introduced to current society and helps them control their powers.

Comment: Under the circumstances you describe, the answer is a simple "sure, why not?" but maybe you'd like to clarify a bit. That might also fend off those close votes.

Comment: How many children? What is the extent of their powers? How centralized is their concentration? Do they know about each other? Do they know how important it is to keep their powers hidden? There are a lot of additional questions to ask in this case. Additionally, your question is limited to a simple 'yes' or 'no' answer. Consider rewording it in such a way as to provide people with the opportunity to give you new ideas on your creation rather than just validation.

Comment: What would "from the past" mean? Do they have the mentality of someone from 1960? 1560? Or 60 BC? Do they speak the language of the nation wherein they reside?

I'd consider changing your question from a "Could" to a "How could," a "What would happen if," or an "Is it feasible for", if you do not ask such further questions in the body text.

Comment: This idea is very similar to an existing TV show. http://abc.go.com/shows/resurrection

Comment: This is either *way* too broad or *way* too narrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is "How could they be introduced" or "can they be introduced".

*Can* they? They most certainly can. I refer you to the Percy Jackson series or the Nicholas Flamel/Alchemyst series.

As for *how* they should be implemented, that's your call. It's your story, and you can explain it however you want. The thing to keep in mind though would be the mannerisms of the characters; for example, a character from Nazi Germany versus modern-day.